# Eigendecomposition of some Laplacian matrices

Tags: matrices, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Consider the following matrix:
$$L(P_5):=\left[\begin{array}{@{}rrrrr@{}} 
  1&-1& 0& 0& 0\\
 -1& 2&-1& 0& 0\\
  0&-1& 2&-1& 0\\
  0& 0&-1& 2&-1\\
  0& 0& 0&-1& 1
\end{array}\right].$$
Its eigendecomposition is well known: its eigenvectors are the columns of the type-II Discrete Cosine Transform, up to a transposition; and its eigenvalues are the roots of a type-II Chebyschyov polynomial after certain linear transformation, and zero.

Now take a look at these matrices:
$$L(\mathcal{D}_6):=\left[\begin{array}{@{}rrrrrr@{}}
  2&-1&-1& 0& 0& 0\\
 -1& 3&-1&-1& 0& 0\\
 -1&-1& 4&-1&-1& 0\\
  0&-1&-1& 4&-1&-1\\
  0& 0&-1&-1& 3&-1\\
  0& 0& 0&-1&-1& 2
\end{array}\right],$$
$$L(\mathcal{M}_8):=\left[\begin{array}{@{}rrrrrrrr@{}}
  3&-1&-1&-1& 0& 0& 0& 0\\
 -1& 4&-1&-1&-1& 0& 0& 0\\
 -1&-1& 5&-1&-1&-1& 0& 0\\
 -1&-1&-1& 6&-1&-1&-1& 0\\
  0&-1&-1&-1& 6&-1&-1&-1\\
  0& 0&-1&-1&-1& 5&-1&-1\\
  0& 0& 0&-1&-1&-1& 4&-1\\
  0& 0& 0& 0&-1&-1&-1& 3
\end{array}\right],$$
and so on.  Are there closed-form expresions for the eigendecomposition of these new matrices?  If so, I am curious whether the eigendecomposition can be escalated to higher order matrices (hence the subscripts.)